# Bootstrap 4 navbar with Angular - how to activate item

Tags: angular-ui-router, bootstrap-4

I am putting together B4 navbar with Angular router states. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav" id="myTab" role="tablist">
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" ui-sref="state1" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" ui-sref="state2" href="#">Link</a>
 </li>
</ul>

<div ui-view></div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[ "ui.router", "AppCtrls"]);

 myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
 $stateProvider.state("state1", {
    url: "#",
    template: "<p>State 1</p>",
    controller: "Ctrl1"
  }).state("state2", {
    url: "#",
    template: "<p>State 2</p>",
    controller: "Ctrl2"
  });
});

var ctrls = angular.module("AppCtrls", []);

ctrls.controller( "Ctrl1", function($scope) {
console.log("Ctrl1 loaded.");
});

ctrls.controller( "Ctrl2", function($scope) {
     console.log("Ctrl2 loaded.");
});
```

What I want to achieve is to have a default active item with its content being shown. I am setting up the first link to active but it doesn't do anything. 
Here is my
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/789Ks/422/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code for HTML :

```
    <ul class="nav" id="myTab" role="tablist">
   <li class="nav-item" ui-sref-active="active">
      <a class="nav-link" ui-sref="name1">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" ui-sref-active="active">
     <a class="nav-link" ui-sref="name2">Link</a>
 </li>
</ul>

<div ui-view></div>
```

And this Angular :

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[ "ui.router"]);

 myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvide) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
$stateProvider
    .state('name1',{
        url: "/name1",
        conontroller:'ctrl1',
        templateUrl: "name1.html"
    })
    .state('name2',{
        url: "/name2",
        conontroller:'ctrl2',
        templateUrl: "name2.html"
    })
});


myApp.controller( "ctrl1", function($scope) {
console.log("Ctrl1 loaded.");
});

myApp.controller( "ctrl2", function($scope) {
     console.log("Ctrl2 loaded.");
});
```